# Coloring Vector if it points at (0,0,0) or (1,1,1)

Tags: plotting, color, vector

I'm trying to plot a 3D vector field on a cubic space between [0,1]. I wanted to color the vectors based on their direction, where if they point towards (0,0,0) or the closer corners (1,0,0), (0,1,0), and (0,0,1) they have a color, and if they point towards (1,1,1) or its close corners they have another color.

For this, I tried using:

```
colors = Function[{x, y, z, vx, vy, vz}, With[{vec = {vx, vy, vz}}, If[Dot[vec, {1, 1, 1}] <= 0, Blue, Orange]]]
```

However, as you can see in the produced image in the bottom right corner, around the point (1,0,0) there are both orange and blue vectors pointing towards the corner, even though this corner is closer to (0,0,0) than to (1,1,1).

I'm sure I have to consider not just the vector direction, but the position as well. But I'm unsure on how to proceed.

Can anyone lend a hand?

Additionally, if anyone could also help on how to plot the points where the vector magnitude is close to 0, a fixed point, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

[image: The current result]